# Anti-forgery unique serial number generation

Tags: php, mysql, batch-file, random, unique

I am trying to generate a random serial number to put on holographic stickers in order to let customers check if the purchased product is authentic or not.

Preface:
Once you input that and query that code it will be nulled, so next time you do it again you receive a message that the product might be fake because the code is already used.

Considering that I should make this system for a factory that produces no more than 2/3 millions pieces a year, for me is a bit hard understand how to set up everything, at least the 1st time…

I thought about 20 digits code in 4 groups (no letters because must be very easy for the user read and input the code)

```
12345-67890-98765-43210
```

This is what I think is the easiest way to do everything:

```
function mycheckdigit()
{
...
return $myserial;
}
$mycustomcode="123";
$qty=20000;
$myfile = fopen("./thefile.txt","w")  or die("Houston we got a problem here");
//using a txt file for a test, should be a DB instead...
for($i=0;$i<=$qty;$i++) {
    $txt = date("y").$mycustomcode.str_pad(gettimeofday()['usec'],6,STR_PAD_LEFT).random_int(1000000,9999999). "\n";
    //here the code to make check digits
    mycheckdigit($txt);
    fwrite($myfile,$myserial);
}
fclose($myfile);
```

- The 1st group identifying something like year: 18 and 3 custom code
- The 2nd group include `microtime` (`gettimeofday()['usec']`)
- The 3rd completely random
- last group including 3 random number and a check digit for group 1 and a check digit for group 2

in short:

```
Y= year
E= part of the EAN or custom code
M= Microtime generated number (gettimeofday()['usec'])
D= random_int() digits
C= Check Digit

YYEEE-MMMMM-MDDDD-DDDCC
```

In this way, I have a prefix that changes every year, I can recognize what brand is the product (so I could use one DB source only) and I still have enough random digits to be - maybe - quite unique if I consider that I will “pick-up” only a portion of the numbers from `1,000,000` and `9,999,999` and split it following using above sorting

Some questions for you:

- Do you think I have enough combinations to not generate same code in one year considering 2 million codes? I would not use a lookup in the DB for the same code if it is not really necessary because could slow down batch generation (executed in batch during production process)
- Could be better put some also unique identifier, like a day of the year (001-365) and make `random_int()` 3 digits shorter? Please Consider that I will generate codes monthly and not daily (but I think there is no big change in uniqueness)

> - Considering that backend in PHP I am thinking to use `mt_rand()` function, could be a good approach?

**UPDATE:** After the @apokryfos suggestion, I read more about UUID generation and similar I found a good compromise using `random_int()` instead.
Because I just need digits, so HEX hashes are not useful for my needs and making things more complicated

I would avoid using complex cryptographic things like RSA keys and so on…
I don’t  need that level of security and complexity, I just need a way to generate a unique serial number, most unique as possible that is not easy to be guessed and nulled if you don’t scratch the sticker (so number creation should not be made A to Z, but randomly)

Comment: instead of `YYrrr` (random), you could use `YYYDDD` (day of month, 001-365) or `YYcwD` (CalenderWeek 01-52 and dayOfWeek (1-7). With more numbers you generate by a fixed algorithm, the lower the probabilty of a duplicate. Depending on your (reliable) time resolution, you could go down to minutes, seconds and even milliseconds, which probably leaves you with onlya few digits left - For this, a "count" is better than random. You could even add some "disguise" like adding 543 to `DDD`, swapping places etc. Interesting question, but sadly "off Topic" on SO.

Comment: @Stephan thanks for your suggestion, is an easy and interesting implementation that makes code "cleaner".
About the "off topic" I thought that was right place SO, sorry for that. 
If you would suggest me the right place where to ask this kind of question I'll keep in mind for the next one.

Comment: Questions like this tend to be redirected to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), but I'm not sure,if it's on-topic there. An OnTopic question here at SO is like "I try to ..., but I have problems to get the following code to do what I expect". If you are willing to accept some downvotes, keep the question until it gets closed and hope for some helpful feedback.

Comment: @Stephan i fixed up the question and i also updated after some tests and researches on SO. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can play with 11 random digits per year so that's 11 digit numbers 1 to 99999999999 (99.9 billion is a lot more than 2 million) so w.r.t. enough combinations I think you're covered.

However using `mt_rand` you're likely to get collisions. Here's a way to plan your way to 2 million random numbers before using the database:

```
<?php
$arr = [];
while (count($arr) < 1000000) {
    $num = mt_rand(1, 99999999999);
    $numStr = str_pad($num,11,0,STR_PAD_LEFT); //Force 11 digits
    if (!isset($arr[$numStr])) {
        $arr[$numStr] = true;
    } 
}
$keys= array_keys($arr);
```

The number of collisions is generally low (the first collision occurs at at about 300 000 - 500 000 numbers generated so it's pretty rare.

Each value in the array `$keys` is an 11 digit number which is random and unique.

This approach is relatively fast but be aware it will need quite a bit of memory (more than 128MB).

This being said, a more generally used method is to generate a [universally unique identifier (UUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) which is a lot more likely to be unique and will therefore does not really need checking for uniqueness.